# Conditional seems to go unevaluated

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a couple of models set up like this in a Rails 4 project.

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contracts

  def balance
    unpaid_contracts.sum(&:sum_total)
  end

private

  def unpaid_contracts
    unpaid_contracts = []
    contracts.each do |c|
      unpaid_contracts << c if c.unpaid? # This is the problem
    end
  end

end
```

**contract.rb**

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :student

  def unpaid?
    return true if invoices.blank?
    invoices.each do |i|
      return true if i.current_status != "paid" && i.current_status != "rescinded"
    end
  end
end
```

No matter what I do all contracts get added to `unpaid_contracts`. There are no invoices at all in the db, so I would assume `unpaid?` should always evaluate to true, right?

In fact, even if I change the conditional to `unpaid_contracts << c if false` the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried loading a contract and using `.unpaid?` What does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to your return value:

```
  def unpaid_contracts
    unpaid_contracts = []
    contracts.each do |c|
      unpaid_contracts << c if c.unpaid? # This is the problem
    end
  end
```

You're returning `contracts.each`, which is to say *all* contracts, not `unpaid_contracts`.

This would fix it...

```
  def unpaid_contracts
    unpaid_contracts = []
    contracts.each do |c|
      unpaid_contracts << c if c.unpaid? # This is the problem
    end
    unpaid_contracts
  end
```

But this is better:

```
  def unpaid_contracts
    contracts.select(&:unpaid?)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try the following

1. Private methods are only for when you are not going to use the Class or an instance of the Class, so try taking it out.
2. Slightly neater way of coding it:

   ```
   def unpaid_contracts
      contracts.select { |contract| contract.invoices.count == 0}
   end
   ```
3. As mentioned by @meagar, you are not returning the right variable.

Comment: That code seems to work for me like this `contracts.select { |contract| contract.pending? }`

Thanks for the heads up about private methods!